# Why does this array of structure only access the first element & shows segmentation fault for the rest of the elements?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I've spent three hours trying to figure out why I'm getting a segmentation fault in this particular case & I went through a lot of questions on this topic but still I couldn't relate it to my case.

Now I seem to know what is the problem but I don't know why.

My array of structures doesn't seem to be initialized properly.

All the values which I take as input from the user are displayed properly in the main function but when I go inside the calc_bonus(..) function, it runs correct for i=0, but gives segmentation fault for i=1 & there on.

This was a simple assignment question which I solved successfully( got all the test cases right using a naive approach) but I want to know where my main solution went wrong.
Here's the initial code where I'm trying to find out netsalary & bonus.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Employee
{
    char empid[50];
    int basicsalary;
    int pf;
    int mediclaim;
    float salespercentage;
    int bonus;
    float netsalary;
};

int calc_NetSalary(struct Employee**,int);
int calc_Bonus(struct Employee**,int);

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    puts("Enter total records");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct Employee *emp = malloc(n*sizeof(*emp));
    int flag[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        puts("Enter the employee id");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s",emp[i].empid);
        puts("Enter the basic salary");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].basicsalary);
        puts("Enter the PF amount");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].pf);
        puts("Enter the mediclaim amount");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].mediclaim);
        puts("Enter the sales percentage");
        scanf("%f",&emp[i].salespercentage);
        if(emp[i].basicsalary<0||emp[i].pf<0||emp[i].mediclaim<0||emp[i].salespercentage<0)
            flag[i]=1;
        else
            flag[i]=0;
        emp[i].bonus=calc_Bonus(&emp,i);
        emp[i].netsalary=calc_NetSalary(&emp,i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(flag[i])
            printf("Unable to calculate salary for the ID %s\n",emp[i].empid);
        else
           printf("Net salary for the ID %s is Rs.%.2f\n",emp[i].empid,emp[i].netsalary);
    }
    free(emp);
}

int calc_Bonus(struct Employee **emp,int i)
{

    if(emp[i]->basicsalary<=7000 && emp[i]->salespercentage<=10)
        return 1500;
    else if(emp[i]->basicsalary<=7000 && emp[i]->salespercentage>=10)
        return 3000;
    else if(emp[i]->basicsalary<=15000 && emp[i]->basicsalary>7000 && emp[i]->salespercentage<=10)
        return 2000;
    else if(emp[i]->basicsalary<=15000 && emp[i]->basicsalary>7000 && emp[i]->salespercentage>=10)
        return 4000;
    else if(emp[i]->basicsalary>15000 && emp[i]->salespercentage<=10)
        return 2500;    
    else if(emp[i]->basicsalary>15000 && emp[i]->salespercentage>=10)
        return 4500;

}

int calc_NetSalary(struct Employee **emp,int i)
{
    int a=emp[i]->basicsalary-emp[i]->pf-emp[i]->mediclaim+emp[i]->bonus;
    return a;
}
```

Now I've tried to debug it by printing out the values of bonus & netsalary for different iterations & it works only for i=0
& gives 12 segmentation fault core dump.

Can anyone point out exactly what I'm doing wrong here?

I checked to see that emp variables had been initialised though the main problem starts at the second iteration when I call the calc_Bonus(..) function.
The value of emp[1].basicsalary gives that error but I don't know why.

EDIT:
What I did & got as output compared to what should be the output.

```
Enter total records
2
Enter the employee id
428
Enter the basic salary
5500
Enter the PF amount
550
Enter the mediclaim amount
1203
Enter the sales percentage
8.5
Enter the employee id
430
Enter the basic salary
12000
Enter the PF amount
350
Enter the mediclaim amount
650
Enter the sales percentage
10.5
/home/p10301/.vpl_launcher.sh: line 12: 11946 Segmentation fault        (core dumped) ./vpl_execution
```

What the expected output should be:

```
Net salary for the ID 428 is Rs.5247.00
Net salary for the ID 430 is Rs.15000.00
```

Comment: You should step through line-by-line in a debugger to see where the behaviour diverges from what you expected.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](/help/mcve)

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS I did that & am still getting the same error.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I kind of did that & like I said in the post it diverges in the second iteration of the function calc_Bonus(..). I don't know why that happens so I checked if the value of i was causing it & that wasn't the case.

Comment: @ShwetankKumar I was wrong, I just misread your code.

Comment: Which line crashes the program?

Comment: @ErikW The first line of the function calc_Bonus during the second iteration when the value of i=1

Comment: `struct Employee **emp` That is a pointer to a pointer. Not a pointer to an array. So when you do `emp[0]` that gives the original array address. But any other index is invalid as you do not have an array of pointers but rather an array of struct. Instead you should pass in the original array as `struct Employee *emp` and access as `emp[i].salespercentage`

Comment: I know that & the first time I solved I used that approach only but the constraint states that the function definition should be the same as I've written in the provided code. I know this isn't a tough question, I'm just curious & like you stated that it is a pointer to a pointer but there must be some way I could access the variables inside my structure even when I pass a pointer to pointer.

Comment: You should add that constraint into the question. In that case you need to change the references to be: `(*emp)[i].salespercentage`

Comment: @kaylum he would probably get points deduced for that, because it's just circumventing the intent of the instructor, which is creating an array of pointers.

Comment: @n.m. Good point. The OP didn't state the full requirements and I didn't think further into the intent of the function signature (I should have).

Comment: @kaylum OTOH requiring an array and an index where an individual object would naturally suffice isn't exactly a pinnacle of software engineering either, so I dunno what they were thinking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `emp` declared in `main()` like so:

```
struct Employee *emp = malloc(n*sizeof(*emp));
```

, `emp` is a single pointer (as opposed to an array of pointers) to space large enough for several `struct Employee` objects; semantically, it points specifically to the first of those objects.

In that case, this call ...

```
calc_Bonus(&emp,i)
```

... and the similar call to `calc_NetSalary(&emp,i)` are consistent with those functions' prototypes, but inconsistent with their implementations and the joint meaning of their argument lists (as implied by their implementations) when `i` is nonzero.  Specifically, consider this expression from `calc_Bonus()`:

```
emp[i]->basicsalary
```

Since `emp` is declared there as a `struct Employee **`, let's rewrite that to replace the `[]` operation with the equivalent pointer-arithmetic based expression:

```
(*(emp + i))->basicsalary
```

Now the problem should be clearer, but you have to be careful to distinguish between the `emp` of `calc_Bonus()` and the `emp` of `main()`, which differ in both type and value.  The `emp` in `calc_Bonus()`, as called, points to a **scalar** (`emp` of `main()`), so if you add a nonzero integer to it and attempt to dereference the result then you get undefined behavior.

Given the current function signature, that expression and all the similar ones would need to be rewritten in this form:

```
(*emp)[i].basicsalary
```

... or this one ...

```
(*emp + i)->basicsalary
```

But I think a better solution would be to reduce the level of indirection by rewriting the function like so:

```
int calc_Bonus(struct Employee *emp, int i) {
    if (emp[i].basicsalary <= 7000 && emp[i].salespercentage <= 10)
        return 1500;
    // ...
}
```

and calling it from `main()` like so:

```
calc_Bonus(emp,i);
```

There are several other valid alternatives that would also be better than the original code.

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand this now.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating a sequence of `struct Employee` objects (i.e. `malloc(n * sizeof(struct Employee))`, but in function `calc_bonus` you treat them as an array of pointers to such `struct Employee` objects (and you pass a pointer to such a sequence of pointers, i.e. `struct Employee**`).
Hence, in function `calc_bonus`, when you write `emp[i]`, then you get back the `i`th pointer in `emp`. But `emp` does not contain pointers, it contains the employee objects. So `emp[i]` will return a value that is treated as a pointer, but the pointer value will point to something arbitrary, which is very likely on a `struct Employee`-object. And dereferencing such an "invalid" pointer yields undefined behaviour, which might become visible as a segmentation fault.

To overcome this, define and use `calc_Bonus` as follows:

```
int calc_Bonus(struct Employee[],int);

int calc_Bonus(struct Employee emp[],int i)
{
    if(emp[i].basicsalary<=7000 && emp[i].salespercentage<=10) {
    ...
}

int main () {
  ...
  emp[i].bonus=calc_Bonus(emp,i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calc_Bonus() method should not have the array and index number as parameters.
It should just have one parameter - a pointer to an instance of Employee.
And it need not return anything, since you are just filling in a field of that employee:

```
void calc_Bonus( Employee *e ) {
   if(e->basicsalary<=7000 && e->salespercentage<=10) {
     e->bonus = xxx;
   } else if ( ... ) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Then just call it using

```
   calc_Bonus( &emp[i] );
```